# How to reshape the dimensions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, vector

This is my data in R, it is a list:

```
$class
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30 
<=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K  >50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K 
   31    32    33
```

I wish to have it in the below format:

```
 [1] <=50K <=50K <=50K >50K  <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K >50K  >50K  <=50K <=50K >50K  <=50K <=50K >50K  <=50K >50K  >50K  <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K
  [30] <=50K >50K  <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K >50K  <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K >50K  >50K  <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K
  [59] <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K >50K  <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K >50K  <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K >50K  >50K  <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K >50K 
  [88] <=50K >50K  >50K  >50K  <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K <=50K
```

I tried doing it in the below way, but I am unable to achieve the correct format, how do I reshape it?

```
a <- as.numeric(adult_test_pred[[1]])
a
```

The output of a is:

```html
   [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  [88] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a named vector, we need `unname`

```
unname(adult_test_pred[[1]])
```

If it is a named `factor`, just use `as.character`, which will also remove the names

```
as.character(adult_test_pred[[1]])
```

e.g.

```
> v1 <- c("1" = "sam", "2" = "hello")
> as.character(v1)
[1] "sam"   "hello"
```